# Problem at boot-time: "Loading user-defined modules [FAIL]"

Tags: kernel, arch-linux, kernel-modules, startup

After I updated my Kernel to version 3.0, i always get this line when my Arch-Linux system is booting up:

```
Loading User-specified Modules    [BUSY]    [FAIL]
```

I have no idea what could cause this to happen. My `MODULES`-array in the `/etc/rc.conf`-file looks like this:

```
MODULES=(fuse wl !b43 !ssb !usblp vboxdrv vboxnetflt)
```

I checked the modules which are loaded (using `modprobe`) and they all load just fine.

My idea was, that one of the Blacklisted modules in my `MODULES`-array got kicked out of the kernel or renamed and now the system can't find it (to block it). So i checked all available kernel-modules using:

```
ls -R /lib/modules/3.0-ARCH/kernel/ | grep <module-name>
```

I found all of the modules in the array except for the last two (from VirtualBox). However, trying to manually load them with `modprobe` works and `lsmod` shows that they are probably loaded after boot.

Also, I checked the `/var/log/kernel.log`-logfile (nothing obvious here).

So, I need ideas on what could probably cause this to happen or where I can find the corresponding logfile (since there is a `daemons.log`-file, but no `modules.log`-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blacklisting of modules in the `MODULES` array is deprecated, as announced [here](https://www.archlinux.org/news/changes-to-module-blacklisting/). Perhaps this is the cause.

Comment: Blacklisting the modules in `/etc/modprobe.d` fixed the boot-time error. A quick `lsmod | grep <modules>` shows, that none of the blacklisted modules is loaded. Thanks for the help on this one!

Answer (score 2):

If you can, find the startup script that loads the modules (you could use `grep -RF "User-specified Modules" /etc/` for example), open it, and go through it step-by-step (pasting each command in your terminal).